# Q. Check if 2 arrays have the same values in the same order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have looked at other posts that supposedly have solved this issue, but this method still doesn't work for me.
I had run into an error in a larger program I was writing but I narrowed the error to this method.

I set a cell to =isMatch( {1,2,3} , {1,2,3} ) to verify my method works. The cell computes to False, and I don't know why or how to fix it.

Before I checked stackoverflow, I had originally written code identical to the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025893/how-to-check-identical-array-in-most-efficient-way).

Here is the code I currently have.

```
function isMatch(arr1,arr2){//Returns True if same Array values in same location
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i =0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316616/)

Comment: This `isMatch( {1,2,3} , {1,2,3} )` should be this `isMatch( [1,2,3] , [1,2,3])`

Comment: @Cooper It's a Google sheets formula array. In sheets, `={1,2}` in formula is `[[1,2]]` and `={1;2}` is `[[1],[2]]`. You can directly type  it in sheets to see

Comment: Thanks.    You can tell I don't use formulas much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a 2D array. `{1,2,3}` === `[[1,2,3]]` and not `[1,2,3]`.

To compare a n dimensional array, you can recurse:

```js
function isMatch(arr1, arr2) {
  if (typeof arr1 !== typeof arr2)
    throw new TypeError('Arrays or elements not of same type!');
  if (Array.isArray(arr1))
    return (
      arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((e, i) => isMatch(e, arr2[i]))
    );
  return arr1 === arr2;
}

console.info(isMatch([[1], [2]], [[1], [2]]));
console.info(isMatch([[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]));
console.info(isMatch([[1, 2]], 1));
```

- [2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115863/)
- [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)