# Why isn't the array I'm using in javascript for google sheets 2d?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've seen the following [SO quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115863/how-do-you-resolve-a-the-parameters-number-dont-match-the-method-signature) and I thought my array was 2d.  Here's my code:

```
var testingArray = [ 
    { poolIndex: 0 },
    { stakingStrategy: 'masterchef' },
    { farmName: 'sushiChef' }
    ];


function placeSushiData () {
   let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();            
   let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('test spreadsheet');   
   let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(11,2, 2, testingArray.length)

   targetRange.setValues(testingArray)
}
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.
```

Why isn't my array 2d?  If it isn't, how do I make it 2D?  Or, more broadly, how do I get it into two rows of my google sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2d array is a matrix. basically, it's an array of arrays of values.

So, your data should look something like this:

```js
const testingArray = [ 
  [ "2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99" ],
  [ "stakingStrategy", "masterchef", '' ],
  [ "farmName", "sushiChef", '' ]
];
```

Here's [an example from the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Comment: It really should be rectangular and your link does not link directly to an example

Answer (score 4):

```
function placeSushiData () {
  var A = [["poolIndex", 0 ],["stakingStrategy",'masterchef'],[ "farmName", 'sushiChef' ]];   
   let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();            
   let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');   
   let rg = sh.getRange(11,2, A.length, A[0].length)
   rg.setValues(A)
}
```

Output:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  | poolIndex | 0 |
|  | stakingStrategy | masterchef |
|  | farmName | sushiChef |
|  |  |  |

Comment: Thank you!  So, I need to have that data in brackets; An array of arrays.  Got it.

Comment: No brackets for 2d arrays.  And the arrays must be rectangular.  Although you can include nulls

Comment: Sorry, but aren't `[]` brackets?  Are they called something else?

Comment: I call these brackets {};

Comment: Well I guess they're both brackets there are curly brackets and square brackets [ref](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/parentheses/#:~:text=These%20%7B%20%7D%20have%20a%20variety%20of,signify%20hugging%20in%20electronic%20communication.) So  I should have said no curly brackets use square brackets instead.

Comment: Deep, deep trivia: `{` can also be referred to as an "opening brace" or even a "left brace", as well as a "left curly bracket". But `[` is not used with the word "brace" - only with the word "bracket" as in "left square bracket". I am basing this on the Unicode nomenclature - see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007b/index.htm) and [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005b/index.htm).  @DBWeinstein