Error copying 2d array contents to Google Sheets column
In GAS, I have a 2d array that I have populated with data and after the function runs I want to be able to push that data into a single column in a Google Sheet. I keep getting an error that the number of rows in the data doesn't match the number of rows in the range. Looking for some extra eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong.
var allExpensesStatus = [];
for (i = 0; i < somevar.length; i++)
{
   allExpensesStatus.push([i,"some text"]);
}

spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MySheet").getRange("H2:H" + allExpensesStatus.length).setValues(allExpensesStatus);


When I use a single dim array I get this error which I thought was telling me it needed to be 2d, but I guess I'm mistaken? I changed the .push to only put in the text, and I get this error now: Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

I got the same error when testing your code.  Can you make your goal a bit more clear?  Are you just trying to output the content of an array?

Correct, that is all I am trying to do. Honestly there is nothing else to the code block at the moment. What you see in my original post is it. All I've changed is to make the .push to be .push("some text").

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115863/

Since your range "H2:H" starts in row 2 you should add 1 to the ending row or length+1
I notice each row has 2 elements so the range should be expanded to “H2:I”.
spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MySheet").getRange("H2:I" + (allExpensesStatus.length+1)).setValues(allExpensesStatus);

I always prefer to use this form of getRange.  It's sure to fit the array size.
spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MySheet").getRange(2,8,allExpensesStatus.length,allExpenseStatus[0].length).setValues(allExpensesStatus);


I tried that but unfortunately get the same error: Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

Tried your updated version and I still get the previous error. When looking at the help text for the .setValues function, it says it requires a two dimensional array. That is why I had that setup originally. I tried putting that back so that the push statements now do a 2d array:
allExpensesStatus.push([i,"NOT REVIEWED"]);

However, when I run this I get a different error: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1.

@codeMinion170 The last one should work with your original code in the question: spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MySheet").getRange(2,8,allExpensesStatus.length,allExpenseStatus[0].length).setValues(allExpensesStatus);

It does! I had a typo that was causing the issue, and copying pasting directly from here again let me find it. Thank you!

@codeMinion1701 You're welcome.
